# Python Opencv output.avi screengrab color is blue intensive

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

When I try to perform a video capture of the screen, the output file always has more blue in the output. It never copies the color exactly.

I have tried a few different Codec's in for the fourcc to be used with opencv and video writer. I have tried MJPG with .mjpg, and XVID .avi filetypes. Also tried adding a .convert('RBGA') to the end of the ImagrGrab.grab() line. ex ImageGrab.grab().convert('RGBA')

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageColor
import cv2
import numpy as np

def run():
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
    vid = cv2.VideoWriter('test5.mjpg', fourcc, 8, (width, height))
    while(True):
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, width, height))#testSpec: bbox=(0, 0, 800, 1000)
        img_np = np.array(img)
        # frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        vid.write(img_np)
        ## Visually inspect recording in progress, by showing frame. 
        # cv2.imshow("frame", img_np) #frame 
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == 27:
            break
    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows();
```

Code works well for fullscreen capture. It just makes everything blue. It mostly changes all reds to deep blue. its very annoying.

Comment: OpenCV use BGR color instead RGB so you have to convert it before writing to file

Comment: Would that be implemented in the convert section?

Comment: ValueError: conversion from RGB to BGR not supported

Comment: img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, width, height)).convert('BGR')#bbox=(0, 0, 800, 1000)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1061, in convert
    im = im.convert(mode, dither)

Comment: This is with changing the fourcc to XVID and the writer to .avi. in MJPG it just didn't even run. 
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x47504a4d/'MJPG' is not supported with codec id 7 and format 'mjpeg / raw MJPEG video'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: I can't use ImageGrab because it need Windows and I use Linux. Normally I can get image from Camera and write to file without converting. Maybe all functions works with BGR and you have to conver ImageGrab from RGB to BGR, not BGR to RGB.

Comment: How would that conversion be done within this method?

Comment: ImageGrab.grab() comes from PIL (Pillow), which is platform agnostic.

Comment: Pillow works on all platforms, but ImageGrab works only on Windows and Mac. When you run ImageGrab on Linux then it display warning with this information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OpenCV expects an image to be BGR. Your screen grab is RGB. So for openCV to display/save the image correctly you need to convert it to BGR. Seems your nearly there, as you apparently figured out how to convert to gray. Converting to BGR is basically the same:

```
    img_np = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("img", img_np)
```

This results in the following:
Left is unprocessed, right is color converted. The logo should indeed be blue.

[image]

Comment: The grey doesn't work correctly either it turns out., I did t the BGR2RGB to have the same result. When the recording window overlaps the main window it appears to work properly.

Comment: Are you witing the adapted frame? `vid.write(img_np)` in your code above should be `vid.write(frame)` to save the converted image.